# Convert php query result into json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following code that queries multiple tables to get information about activities. I would like to convert the query result into array and call it whenever needed.
My question is: can this query be converted into array?

```
<?php
function view_full_activity($activity_field){
            global $connection;

        $contact_id = $_REQUEST['contact_id'];
        $activity_id = $_REQUEST['activity_id'];
        $get = "SELECT * FROM activity_base WHERE activity_id = '$activity_id' "
                                    or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connection));
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $get);
    //Get activity base information
        while ($activity = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $activity_related_to_id = $activity ['activity_related_to_id'];
            $activity_id = $activity['activity_id'];
            $activity_type_id = $activity['activity_type_id'];
      $activity_entity_type_id = $activity['activity_entity_type_id'];
            $activity_title = $activity['activity_title'];
            $activity_due_date = $activity['activity_due_date'];
            $activity_created_by = $activity['activity_created_by'];
            $activity_created_on = $activity['activity_created_on'];
            $activity_status_code_id = $activity['activity_status_code_id'];
            $activity_type_icon;
            $activity_due_date = $activity['activity_due_date'];
      $activity_create_date = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($activity['activity_created_on']));

      //Reverse Date
      $activity_due_date = date("m-d-Y ", strtotime($activity_due_date));

            if ($activity_type_id == "1"){
                $activity_type_icon = "fa fa-envelope";
            }else if ($activity_type_id == "3"){
                $activity_type_icon = "fa fa-suitcase";
            }else if ($activity_type_id == "2"){
                $activity_type_icon = "fa fa-phone";
            }

      if ($activity_entity_type_id == "1") {
        $acitvity_url = "acct_id";
        $acitivty_is_for ="accounts_base";
        $page_url = "account-profile.php";
      }else if ($activity_entity_type_id == "2") {
        $acitvity_url = "contact_id";
        $acitivty_is_for ="contacts";
        $page_url = "contact-profile.php";
      }else if ($activity_entity_type_id == "3") {
        $acitvity_url = "contact_id";
        $acitivty_is_for ="contacts";
        $page_url = "contact-profile.php";
      }
          //Get detailed activity information 
      //If activity is Email
    if ($activity_type_id == "1") {
        $email_details = email_activity_details($activity_id);
        while ( $email = mysqli_fetch_assoc($email_details)) {
          $activity_details = nl2br($email['email_message']);

        }
    }else if ($activity_type_id == "2") {
        $call_details = call_activity_details($activity_id);
        while ( $call = mysqli_fetch_assoc($call_details)) {
          $activity_details = $call['call_details'];
          }
        }else if ($activity_type_id == "3") {
        $meeting_details = meeting_activity_details($activity_id);
        while ( $meeting = mysqli_fetch_assoc($meeting_details)) {
          $activity_details = $meeting['meeting_details'];
          }
        }
        //Get creator user info
          $user_query = get_user_info($activity_created_by);
          while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)) {
            $activity_created_by = $user['user_full_name'];
          }
    }

    }     



          ?>
```

Comment: The query cannot be converted, but its result certain can.

Comment: There are some syntax issues in this code though. For example take the line `$activity_type_icon;` What is that meant to do? Also, why so complicated? The result already _is_ an array. Why don't you simply convert certain values _inside_ the array? Or, even better, make the date conversions inside the sql statement?

Comment: @arkascha This is a declaration for a variable that will allow me to change the icon based on the activity type.

Comment: true, it is valid, but it does not make any sense. This is php, just declaring a variable is without point. It only makes sense if you assign a value to it, maybe a default value. Otherwise just leave it away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

Create a variable called `$activity_store` and use the while loop to set the data much in the same way it comes out of the database.

```
//Get activity base information
$activity_store = array();
while ($activity = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $activity_store['activity_related_to_id'] = $activity['activity_related_to_id'];
```

If you need to store information about each activity pulled from the database separately you could add an index and increment it

```
//Get activity base information
$activity_store = array();
$i = 0;
while ($activity = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $activity_store[$i]['activity_related_to_id'] = $activity['activity_related_to_id'];
    ...
    $i++; //increments $i by 1
}
```

Just be aware that later in your code when you refer to `$activity_type_id` you'll now need to refer to '$activity['activity_type_id']`

In terms of returning JSON in php you can use `json_encode` to encode a variable into a JSON format:

```
$json_array = json_encode($variable);
```

Comment: I tried the first option but the array came back empty.

Comment: Never mind, was able to fix it. Thank you for your help.